# Automating file export with multiple layers in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

I have an illustrator file that contains 4 layers with each its own word and 180 more layers. I want to make combinations of the 4 layers with the 180 layers.

I'm currently trying to write the code with the information I found on the internet. I put every layer with the name "Layer" in a new array called fabriks. What I don't know is how to activate the layer "make", "think", "search", "print", and "makerspace" one by one to be exported with the layers in the fabriks array. I created a second array "rooms" to put the 4 words in there.

The code doesn't fully work. It exports the images but some layers overlap each other and sometimes only one layer from the fabriks array is visible but not from the rooms array.

```
var outpath = "~/Desktop/FABRIK MAKERSPACE";
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var makerspace = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("Makerspace");
var make = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("Maakt");
var think = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("Denkt");
var search = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("Zoekt");
var print = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("Print");

var targetLayerName;
var layerName = "Layer";
var fabriks = Array();
var layers = doc.layers;
var rooms = Array();

rooms.push(makerspace);
rooms.push(make);
rooms.push(think);
rooms.push(search);
rooms.push(print);

for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {

    targetLayerName = new String(layers[i].name);

    if (targetLayerName == layerName) {
        fabriks.push(layers[i]);
    }

    layers[i].visible = false;
}
   
var counter = fabriks.length;

for (var i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {

    var roomsName = String(rooms[i].name);
    rooms[i].visible = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < fabriks.length; i++) {

        fabriks[i].visible = true;

        var fname = outpath + "FABRIK_" + roomsName + "_" + counter;
        var f = new File(fname + '.png');
        var exportOptions = new ExportOptionsPNG8(); // or PNG24

        exportOptions.colorCount = 200;
        exportOptions.transparency = true;

        app.activeDocument.exportFile(f, ExportType.PNG8, exportOptions);

        for (var j = 0; j < fabriks[i].length - 1; j++) {
            fabriks[i].visible = false;
        }

        rooms[i].visible = false;
    }
    counter--;
}
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Someone you've never seen before approached you and says..... "I tried to create a logo but I'm no designer. Can someone help me out by creating a logo for me?" -- Sounds kind of bad when you look a the question from a different angle, doesn't it?

Comment: It's not about creating a logo. I already created a logo and nobody needs to help me to create one. Sorry, it came off wrong. Let me rephrase it then. I want to export Layer 1 to 180 with Layer "Name 1", Layer "Name 2", Layer "Name 3", and Layer "Name 4". So When exporting I want combinations Layer 1 + Name 1, Layer 1 + Name 2, ... Layer 180 + Name 1, Etc

Comment: You're asking someone to provide you a script. How is that different than someone asking you to provide a logo free of charge? Work is work. I don't mean to seem unwelcoming in any way. But requests for free work are not what this site is about. We are here to **help** when you are struggling, not complete something for you. Please share what you have tried and where you are having difficulty.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I just saw other people do the same thing. That's why I thought I could ask this question here. I will try to look further online.

Comment: There is a difference in how one asks. See your asking "I have this valuable piece, and i would like to have a solution with this specification". That, is an order for work. While this is fine thats what you want. But people who answer want something too. There is nothing particularily interesting in providing you with said script. Theres nothing mentaly stimulating in it. And you dont particularily sound like youd be interested in learning (teaching you could be a challenge). So i suggest you leave the question a bit more open and ask how one could deal with this.

Comment: ..... yes there are similar requests for free work here. Most are much older questions, many closed or down voted for these reasons... and yes, there are times when someone passing by will copy/paste a script they found or use.. but none of that means it's what the goal of the site is. No harm done. I don't wish to dissuade you from participating at all. I merely felt it warranted clarity that this is a *support site* not a "free work" site.

Comment: I totally understand. I just have difficulties to form the right sentences. I'm definitely trying to code this myself, it's just awkward posting code that isn't close to the solution at all and someone has to fully change it.

Comment: Could using Adobe's built-in Data Merge work for your project?

Comment: @AndrewH I could try. Thank you

Comment: I commend the effort. Thank you! I'm nto a script guru, but I do wonder if naming layers "Layer 1", Layer 2" etc. would be better. You can iterate through the numbers easily via the script. Having multiple layers with the same name *may* be why you are getting double-ups.

Comment: Probably. I named them all "Layer" because only one of them needed to be visible. It was easier to find them without parsing out the number from the layer.

Answer (score 2):

I found something that works.

```
var folder = Folder.selectDialog(); 
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var makerspace = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("Makerspace"); 
var maakt = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("Maakt");
var denkt = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("Denkt");
var zoekt = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("Zoekt");
var print = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("Print");

var targetLayerName;
var layerName = "Layer";
var fabriks = Array();
var layers = doc.layers;

for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {

    targetLayerName = new String(layers[i].name);

    if (targetLayerName == layerName) {
        fabriks.push(layers[i]);
    }

    layers[i].visible = false;
}

for (var j = 0; j < fabriks.length; j++) {

    ExportLayers("Denkt", denkt);
    ExportLayers("Maak", maakt);
    ExportLayers("Zoek", zoekt);
    ExportLayers("Print", print);
    ExportLayers("makerspace", makerspace);
}

function ExportLayers(name, layer) {

    for (var i = 0; i < fabriks.length; i++) {

        fabriks[i].visible = true;
        layer.visible = true;

        var fname = name + "_" + "FABRIK_" + i; 
        var saveInFile = new File(fname); 

        var exportOptions = new ExportOptionsSVG();
        var type = ExportType.SVG;

        exportOptions.embedRasterImages = true;
        exportOptions.embedAllFonts = true;
        exportOptions.fontSubsetting = SVGFontSubsetting.GLYPHSUSED;
        app.activeDocument.exportFile(saveInFile, type, exportOptions);

        var exportOptions = new ExportOptionsPNG24();

        exportOptions.colorCount = 200;
        exportOptions.transparency = true;
        app.activeDocument.exportFile(saveInFile, ExportType.PNG24, exportOptions);

        fabriks[i].visible = false;
        layer.visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is completely cool (and suggested) to mark your own answer as correct if it solves your issue.